# Where can I find Default Relative Path for .Net Data Provider

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-express, sqlconnection

Something is wrong with my `SqlConnection` and causes program to break:

```
SqlConnection konekcija;
konekcija = new SqlConnection (@"Data Source =.\SQLEXPRESS01;
                                 Initial Catalog=NikolaFP;
                                 MultipleActiveResultSetsity =True");
```

I am a little bit confused how does the app know where the server is stored, actually how does it know the `Default Relative Path`?

Server and client are on the same computer.

Comment: Your question is unclear. This connection string specifies the SQL Server host name (`.` indicates local host) and instance name `SQLEXPRESS01`. This is not a file path specification so there is no notion of relative path. SQL Server runs as a service so the app doesn't need to know where it is stored. You need to add `Integrated Security=SSPI` to the connect string to connect with Windows auth. To connect with SQL auth, add `User ID=your-login;Password=your-password`.

Comment: "SQL Server runs as a service so the app doesn't need to know where it is stored" that's what I was confused about. I have never been using this way to connect to database, but I was always using `OleDb` and there you have to specify whole path. Thank you @DanGuzman

Comment: `OleDb` is just another API that can connect to SQL Server and the Data Source specification would be the same. But one can also connect to other data sources (e.g. Excel, Access) using `OleDB` and those may require a file path since those are files rather than a database service.

Comment: Yes, you are right, at that point I was using Access